# How to represent -1 as a byte

Tags: arduino-uno

I want to initialize the value of byte to -1. When I just use `byte num = -1` the value ends up being a decimal 255. I've also tried `int8_t number = -1` and then `byte num = number` but this didn't work either.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Note that while a `byte` cannot have the value -1, it can *store* a pattern of bits which could mean -1 when interpreted instead as a signed type, for example `int8_t`.  On a 2's complement machine like an Arduino the bits that mean -1 in an `int8_t` mean 255 in a `byte`. This kind of thing comes up often in communications when you have an array of bytes that contains the data of fields of other types.  However, you have to be careful when forcibly casting types as the rules of behavior that apply have various gotchas for the unwary, especially if you also cast to a type of different width.

Comment: If you show the code of what you are trying to do, then an appropriate suggestion can be made.  Without that, people can only explain the failure and guess at what your goal is.

Answer (score 6):

A byte can't be -1. A byte can only store numbers between 0 and 255 inclusive.

Depending on the range of your numbers you could use a `char` (-128 to +127) or an `int` (-32768 to +32767).

Answer (score 4):

Simply -1 can't be a byte. A byte is a number from 0-255. -1 is below 0. The Arduino reference defines a byte as "A byte stores an 8-bit unsigned number, from 0 to 255.".

Answer (score -1):

As the other two users have already mentioned:
A byte can only store a number between 0-255, which obviously means that -1 can't be stores as a byte.

I suggest storing it as a positive number, and then when you want to use it just multiply it by -1, which will turn it into a negative one.

***Example to convert positive number as a byte to a negative number:***

```
    negativeNumber = positiveNumberStoredAsByte * -1
```